# Is a permission required to use notifications in an Android app?

Tags: c#, android, notifications, xamarin, android-notifications

(This is using C#/Xamarin)

Is there a permission required to use NotificationManager.Notify(). No notification is appearing, though it should be. Here is my code:

```
int myId = 123123;
Notification nt = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.Icon,"Stuff");
NotificationManager not = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
not.Notify (myId, nt);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, permissions are not required to post a notification.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required):

**A Notification object must contain the following**:

- A small icon, set by *setSmallIcon()*
- A title, set by *setContentTitle()*
- Detail text, set by *setContentText()*

maybe you're missing one of them, as your constructor only has 2 arguments?

In the Xamarin tutorial they are using a Notification.Builder object to post notifications. Maybe that'll work.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked")
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click)
    .SetContentText(String.Format("The button has been clicked {0} times.", _count));

    // Obtain a reference to the NotificationManager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
```

Here's the link to tutorial:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/local_notifications_in_android/

Comment: is that sitll valid with Oreo? regards to channels?